# Yahoo Plus Mail and spam

Tags: yahoo-mail

In the past month or so, I have begun to receive many emails from different senders at a paid Yahoo mail account that I've had for over ten years, whose subject line contains the phrase " you have won " and those words are followed by some product, such as "a pressure washer" or "backpack cooler". Sometimes the word "Congratulations!" is the first word. I mark them as spam, but Yahoo Mail continues to send me these emails. I'm wondering how they are getting through the spam filter. Is there something I'm not doing? Do I have to enable spam blocking somewhere? I don't see anything in settings that would let me turn it on/off.